# How to tell if a "sliced" sphere is greater or less than a hemisphere?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, volume

I have a dataset of volumes that are roughly spheres within a volume. Kind of like a block of swiss cheese or a porous matrix like bone. In a given thickness of this volume, not all spheres will be in the same plane. Some will be cut off. I want to discard all the cut-spheres that are less than a hemisphere. Is there an algorithm or equation that could help me do this? See the attached image for a summary of the problem statement.

[problem statement summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haraq.png)

***Edit***
Thank you to those that asked for clarity in the comments.

The parameters of the spheres that I have are their volumes, whether the spheres were sliced or not. The spheres may also be on the edge of the matrix volume, so even if the center of the sphere lay inside the matrix, it does not mean the sphere is at least a hemisphere, because it could be sliced on the orthogonal side.

See relevant image of matrix description:
[Spheres in a matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDlzd.jpg)

Comment: but what else do you know about the spheres? they do not have constant radius, I presume: do you know the probability distribution of the radius ? or what ?

Comment: Not defined and constrained clearly enough. What about the spheres which are sliced from more then one direction? Is the slice always "produced" with a plane? In general border of some solid of any shape might slice the sphere. The simplest case as presented in your image: if the center of the sphere is outside, then it is less than a heisphere.

Comment: Thank you @GCab. I have added an edit that should clarify. The spheres also have approximately the same radius, but may be slightly different from each other. Also the spheres are not perfectly spherical.

Comment: Thank you @z100. I have added an edit that should clarify. The spheres also have approximately the same radius, but may be slightly different from each other. Also the spheres are not perfectly spherical.

Comment: When you ask about hemispheres, is it only that volume of the partial sphere needs to be more than half the volume of the original sphere? If a sphere is sliced, do all the parts lie in some matrix or are some discarded? Is it important that the sphere is considered to lie in exactly one of these? What if it is split into quarters so that none of the parts are more than half the volume of the sphere?

Comment: Thank you @JaapScherphuis, in the second image you'll see a matrix that contains spheres. This matrix is sliced on 6 planes, and also slices some of the spheres within the matrix. after being sliced, the partial spheres are still single units. There wouldn't be two quarter spheres considered as a hemisphere. I want to discount/ignore any sphere that was cut such that less than a hemisphere remains.

Comment: Hight of section divided by radios less than 1?